# I need to unit test a mat-form-fied input element that would be disable when other field is populated

Tags: typescript, jasmine, angular-material, karma-runner

I have a angular8 materials mat-form-field that has an input type='text' which will be disabled when data was entered into any other fields on that form.

```
const fnDe: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type=text]')).nativeElement;
expect(fnDe.attributes).toContain['disabled'];
```

I am getting 'SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS' message when run the test.

I am using angular8.

Appreciated any help.

Answer (score 1):

First be aware that in your code, `fnBe` is not a `DebugElement` but the native HTML element. From there, you can write your test as follows:

```
const htmlElement: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type=text]')).nativeElement;

expect(htmlElement.getAttributeNames()).toContain('disabled');
```

The `expect` can also be simplified:

```
expect(htmlElement.hasAttribute('disabled')).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, that help me to rewrite my code as follows

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer if you think it was the solution to your question (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)